# Why MSDB transaction log file grew while MSDB was in Simple recovery mode?

Tags: transaction-log, sql-server-2017, msdb

I have Availability Group of 3 servers, and transaction log backups for databases in Availability Group are taken on a secondary replica, each 1 minute

It was working like this for several months

> Now MSDB on this secondary replica is 6 GB data file size (mdf) and is only 4% full and log file size is 14.2 GB (ldf) and is 7% full

I can only remember that I made MSDB `500 MB` both data and log files in the beginning when server was setup...

I thought log file grew because of often transaction log backups and FULL recovery mode - but no, MSDB has SIMPLE recovery mode on that server

So it left me wondering, what caused both data and log file growth for MSDB ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, large growths in MSDB are from adding and deleting the table entries within the backupset tables. Do you have a history purge or anything running?

Comment: Yep weekly below procedures are run: EXEC sp_cycle_errorlog
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_cycle_agent_errorlog -- below SPs run to remove history older than 2 weeks
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_backuphistory 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_purge_jobhistory 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_mailitems_sp 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_log_sp